# Linking netcdf library with Qt

Tags: qt, dll, netcdf

I have a prebuilt version of netcdf Library which I've downloaded from the Unidata website,
Now I am trying to link this Library to Qt 5, to use it in my Qt project. So I looked for some solutions in the internet and I found that I should add these lines to my Project.pro :

```
LIBS += -LC:/netcdf/lib -lnetcdf

INCLUDEPATH += C:/netcdf/include
```

But after runing the project, it doesn't work, so I rerun it with the debuger and it shows me this Message Box 
`(titled "executable Failed") : During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135`

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

The pre-built libraries are built using Microsoft Visual Studio.  As I recall, the C/C++ compiler the Qt SDK uses on Windows is a `mingw`-variant of gcc.  I am not certain if the pre-built netcdf libraries are compatible with the mingw runtime, but it is usually not a good idea to mix C runtimes anyways.

I'm assuming you are using `Qt Creator`; if so, then it may be easier than you think to compile the `netcdf-c` libraries yourself.  Because the netcdf-c project uses `CMake`, you will be able to open it as a project in `Qt Creator`.

### Prerequisites

You will need the following:

- `cmake`: http://cmake.org
- `netcdf-c source code`: http://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-c/releases

#### NetCDF Dependencies

*Note that you will need to install the following dependencies first, depending on the functionality you want from the netcdf library.*

- NetCDF4 support requires libhdf5 and libhdf5_hl, both provided by the `hdf5` package available from http://www.hdfgroup.org.
- DAP support requires `libcurl`.  Google should be able to help you find this.

If you do not need these capabilities, you'll be fine with a straight `netcdf-classic` install.

### Opening netcdf-c as a project in Qt Creator

1. Launch Qt Creator
2. Go to file->open project
3. Navigate to the `netcdf-c` source directory and open the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

This will load the netcdf source as a new project in `Qt Creator`.  At this point it should be pretty straight forward to compile netcdf and install it somewhere on your system to use with your project.

## Incorrect Assumption

If my assumption that you are using `Qt Creator` is wrong, this is all still possible from the command line; it will be, however, a little more involved.